# Delete the subwidgets/entries from a tk::menu widget

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I want to implement a history/recent-files functionality for my Perl/[Tk](http://search.cpan.org/~srezic/Tk-804.029/) program.

Here is a working code excerpt from my program to demonstrate my problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw( -no_match_vars );

use Tk;

my @history_entries = qw(Back To The History);

my $mw      = MainWindow->new();
my $menubar = $mw->Menu();
$mw->configure( -menu => $menubar );
my $file    = $menubar->cascade( -label => '~File' );
my $history = $file->cascade( -label => '~History', );

build_history();

MainLoop();

#===  FUNCTION  ================================================================
#         NAME:  build_history
#      PURPOSE:  Polulate the history
#===============================================================================
sub build_history {
    foreach (@history_entries) {
        $history->command(
            -label    => $ARG,
            -command  => \&some_function,
            -compound => 'left',
        );
    }
    return;
}    # ----------  end of subroutine build_history  ----------
```

As you can see, the entries are created with [**$history->command**](http://search.cpan.org/~srezic/Tk-804.029/pod/Menu.pod#COMMAND_ENTRIES) but how can I delete them every time I call build_history?

The reason I want them deleted is that everytime a user opens a file, the last item (in this case 'History') should be deleted and a new item should be put on top of the list. So that I have a maximum of (in this example) four entries.

Any other ways of implementing this functionality with Tk are welcome.

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE**:
I followed the advice of "mu" and tried to get the subwidgets with the children() function just after the function is called, like this:

```
my @child = $history->children();
foreach my $c ( @child ) {
    if ($c->Exists()){
        $c->destroy;
    }
}
```

The program exits with the error:

```
Can't locate object method "children" via package "Tk::Menu::Cascade" at /home/alex/Desktop/stack_history.pl line 28.
```

Comment: Also with delete i get basically the same error: Can't locate object method "delete" via package "Tk::Menu::Cascade" ...

Comment: I hope it is OK for you that I posted your previously deleted answer as an update, if not I delete it.

Comment: I wasn't even able to do that :-(. I posted my solution.

Comment: The $file submenu gives me the same error as the $history submenu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rebuilding the whole menu. That's how my code looks like atm. I am not proud of it but it works ... I am open to any form of advice.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw( -no_match_vars );

use Tk;

# History entries are stored in array
my @history_entries = qw(Back To The History);

my $mw = MainWindow->new();
$mw->geometry('200x200');

my $menubar = $mw->Menu();

#Build menus
$mw->configure( -menu => $menubar );
build_menu();

$mw->Button(
    -text    => 'Update History',
    -command => \sub {

        #when a user opens a file insert_history is called.
        insert_history();
    }
)->pack( -side => 'bottom', -anchor => 'sw' );

MainLoop();

#===  FUNCTION  ================================================================
#         NAME:  build_menu
#      PURPOSE:  Update/Build the menu
#===============================================================================
sub build_menu {

    #delete the whole menu
    $menubar->delete(1);

    #built it again
    my $file = $menubar->cascade( -label => '~File' );
    my $history = $file->cascade( -label => '~History', );
    foreach (@history_entries) {
        $history->command(
            -label    => $ARG,
            -compound => 'left',
        );
    }

    return;
}    # ----------  end of subroutine build_menu  ----------

#===  FUNCTION  ================================================================
#         NAME:  insert_history
#      PURPOSE:  Do something with the array containing the history entries.
#                Then rebuild the menu.
#===============================================================================
sub insert_history {

    #make something with the array
    my $last_element = pop @history_entries;
    unshift @history_entries, $last_element;

    #update menu
    build_menu();
    return;
}    # ----------  end of subroutine insert_history  ----------
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create a submenu from the menubar first:

```
my $sub_menu = $menubar->Menu(-tearoff => 0);
```

Then you can pass this submenu to the cascade menuitem:

```
$file->cascade( -label => '~History', -menu => $sub_menu);
```

Then you can add/delete menuitems to the submenu:

```
foreach (@history_entries) {
    $sub_menu->command(
        -label    => $ARG,
        -compound => 'left',
    );
}
...
$sub_menu->delete(0);     # Remove first element
```

With this solution you can avoid rebulding the whole menu.